# Handling user authentication using SSO

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid, dropwizard

I am having difficult integrating with SSO with my web application.

I have an sample dropwizard application.
I tried integrating with google and facebook open connect.

```
I thought of 2 approaches for integration
1. fetch the token from frontend js once the user is authenticated using open id, pass that token to the dropwizard server as cookie.
2. fetch the token from the dropwizard server itself and store the set token in cookie while responding to the frontend.
```

I am not sure on which of the above 2 is best or is there any recommend way of integrating with the open connect in dropwizard?

Comment: Assuming you're refering to the access token you could also store it on your server only (e.g. in the session) so as not to expose it directly to the client and any attacker there. If that's not possible I'd go with option 2 and set is as a secure cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I like delegating SSO to well known applications/ libraries specific for the job. Keycloak is the application I’m familiar with. But I suppose some of the points below are application independent. This partial answer is a possible direction of a solution, but I don’t think it’s the recommended way, if there is any such way. Some people will dislike the approach.

The front end is responsible for authentication. But it cannot be trusted to be unmodified since it is in user space. Therefore calls to the back end should be validated for validity and authorization (which should be a back end task anyway).

Keycloak has libraries for well known front and back end implementations that allow easy integration. I’ve used it successfully with Angular and Dropwizard.
Integration with various identity providers can be combined. Therefore it is probably a pretty safe bet for a situation where authentication demands are expected to change. It takes some getting used to the extra layer though, so your mileage may vary.

Some links:

- https://www.keycloak.org
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular
- https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html